# how to create a installer similar to visual studio 2008 setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

i want to know how to create a installer similar to visual studio 2010 setup file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar in which ways?  Have you looked at InstallShield, other commercial options?  Any problems with those?

Comment: gui inteface similar to visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WiX toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is used to create Windows Installer based installers, MSI files. Visual Studio setup uses MSI to make changes to the system. Although MSI is very powerful, it provides limited UI experience, which, however, is quite enough for most setups.

Visual Studio setup uses a regular application that collects information from the user. Then it uses External UI (see [MsiSetExternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384.aspx) function) to monitor and display progress of the installation.

---

Look at [Setup guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee915058.aspx) and make your setup experience *as simple as possible, but not simpler*.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source script driven project called Wix which you could use here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

There are some additional MSI installation file utilities.

Hopefully this helps.